# Use Coderay with Liquid include?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, coderay

I have a Jekyll blog, I am trying to switch from this

```sh
{:lang='bash'}
    #!/bin/sh
    echo 'Hello World!'
```

To this

```sh
{:lang='bash'}
{% include program-w32-build-100.sh %}
```

The `include` inserts the text from the file, and the `lang='bash'` is supposed to highlight it. Since the text in the file is not tabbed, it does not get highlighted. Is there a way to make this happen?

[jason.the-graham.com/2010/11/21/kramdown_support_for_jekyll](http://jason.the-graham.com/2010/11/21/kramdown_support_for_jekyll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky me!

You can do this

```sh
{:lang='bash'}
~~~
{% include rtmpdump-w32-build-100.sh %}
~~~
```

[§ Fenced Code Blocks](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/syntax.html#fenced-code-blocks)